# Listview.setOnItemclicklistener with Searchview

Tags: java

I've a problem with my ListView onClick. I try to explain u by a particule of my code.

So when I'm filtering by
searching c for example
the ActivityA is opening, the
same with Activity B.
So during filtering
they taking the position 0.
Because without filtering
every click open the right Activity.
So, please how can I fix it?

````
private SearchView sv;

Protected void onCreate........

String[] Values = {"a","b","c"};
listView = findViewById(R.id.liste);

sv=findViewById(R.id.searchview);

ArrayAdapter<String>......(.simple_list_item_2,android.R.id.text1,Values);
listView.setAdapter;
sv.setOnQueryTextListener........
//everything here is ok it's filtering well.
//After that,I've my listview.onClick 
listview.setOnItemClickListener()
........(parent, View view, int position, long id){
   if(position == 0){ 
     Itent a = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),AtivityA.class);
startActivity(a)
  }

  if(position == 1){ 
     Intent b = new Intent  (getApplicationContext(),AtivityB.class);
startActivity(b)
  }

 if(position == 2){ 
     Intent c = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),AtivityC.class);
startActivity(c)
  } 
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `position` will always return the first position of the list (which is 0) when you've a single filtered out item as in your case; in order to get the actual position you can search for the first index of the item in the list using `.indexOf()` method. This requires you to convert your array into a an `ArrayList`

```
final String[] Values = {"a", "b", "c"};
final ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList(Values);

myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int pos = list.indexOf(myListAdapter.getItem(position));

        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AtivityA.class);
                startActivity(a);
                return;
            case 1:
                Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AtivityB.class);
                startActivity(b);
                return;
            case 2:
                Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AtivityC.class);
                startActivity(c);

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks u so much for ur help, this code worked for me, it already made one week I searched the solution of this issue. Thanks again, my problem is solved 

Comment: welcome brother, you can also give the `RecylcerView` a try it makes life much easier

Comment: I've some difficulties with recyclerview when it means to open  specific activity by click, it reason why I'm using a listView

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this will help but I would use a switch instead of if statements.

```
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent a = new Intent  (getApplicationContext(),AtivityA.class);
            startActivity(a)
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent b = new Intent  (getApplicationContext(),AtivityB.class);
            startActivity(b)
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent c = new Intent  (getApplicationContext(),AtivityC.class);
            startActivity(c)
            break;

    }
```

Comment: I tried this method, it ain't work, the way is when I'm filtering the last item on my is taking the first place or the position 0. It's the reason why, when I'm filtering the Activity C which is position 2, it becomes position 0 cause of the clearing of the list. But, thank u answering me

Comment: Ok, could you please send the erro message?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.//item:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityA.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.//item:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.//item:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class));
                return true;
             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What I'm supposed to put on item. I don't understand well. Thanks

Comment: Is this an Anroid Project or JavaFX?